# vscode inside WSL vs Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

In tutorial requirement is install vscode in windows and install Remote Development extension pack. Why not just install in wsl?

I've install vscode to wsl. When I run `code` in wsl I get message:

> To use Visual Studio Code with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, please install Visual Studio Code in Windows and uninstall the Linux version in WSL. You can then use the `code` command in a WSL terminal just as you would in a normal command prompt.

> Do you want to continue anyway? [y/N]

> To no longer see this prompt, start Visual Studio Code with the environment variable DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL defined.

Which cons of run vscode in wsl as opposed to  run it in Windows?

Answer (score 4):

The WSL extension splits VS Code into a “client-server” architecture, with the client (the user interface) running on your Windows machine and the server (your code, Git, plugins, etc) running "remotely" in your WSL distribution.

When VS Code is started in WSL, no shell startup scripts are run.

The extension runs commands and other extensions directly in WSL so you can edit files located in WSL or the mounted Windows filesystem (for example /mnt/c) without worrying about pathing issues, binary compatibility, or other cross-OS challenges.

[image]

(source: MSFT DOCUMENTATION)

This is the architectural choice of Windows and - personally speaking - I feel like it's a choice to avoid conflicts and redundancies.

When running the WSL extension, selecting the 'Extensions' tab will display a list of extensions split between your local machine and your WSL distribution.

Installing a local extension, like a theme, only needs to be installed once.

Some extensions, like the Python extension or anything that handles things like linting or debugging, must be installed separately on each WSL distribution. VS Code will display a warning icon ⚠, along with a green "Install in WSL" button, if you have an extension locally installed that is not installed on your WSL distribution.